# How to disable automatic moving of scrollbar?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am using scroll view it has few toggle buttons in that.

When i click on any toggle button scroll view automatically scroll down by some considerable distance..

how can i avoid it??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll_service_associate_container">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:id="@+id/service_associate_title" android:text="@string/service_associate_title"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:background="@drawable/settinglist_background_filled_white" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll_service_associate_details" android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ll_service_associate_cleanliness_main" android:layout_margin="5dip">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_associate_cleanliness_body" android:text="@string/service_associate_cleanliness" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_service_associate_cleanliness_satisfaction" android:text="Very Satisfied" android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"></TextView>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/right" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/btn_service_associate_cleanliness"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView android:background="@color/dark_gray" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/iv_service_associate_cleanliness_divider"></ImageView>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ll_service_associate_skills_main" android:layout_margin="5dip">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_service_associate_skills_body" android:text="@string/service_associate_skills" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_associate_skills_satisfaction" android:text="Very Satisfied" android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"></TextView>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/right" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/btn_service_associate_skills"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView android:background="@color/dark_gray" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/iv_service_associate_skills_divider"></ImageView>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ll_service_associate_information_main" android:layout_margin="5dip">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_service_associate_information_body" android:text="@string/service_associate_information" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tv_service_associate_information_satisfaction" android:text="Veri Satisfied" android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"></TextView>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/right" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/btn_service_associate_information"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ll_customer_comments_container" android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Customer Comments" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <EditText android:background="@drawable/settinglist_background_filled_white" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:minLines="4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/edt_customer_comments_body" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ll_customer_survey_signature_container" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="50dip">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_customer_survey_signature_title" android:text="@string/customer_survey_signature_title" android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ll_customer_survey_signature" android:background="@drawable/settinglist_background_filled_white" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_height="150dip"></LinearLayout>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/btn_clear_sign_customer_survey" android:text="@string/clear_sign" android:background="@drawable/top_bar_button" android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you attach the xml source?